# The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

**I am doing this code to learn a flutter course from Udemy.**
I have downloaded this course that is why I can't take help from there.
I am trying to implement firebase authentication and I have done the same steps that are given in the course but unfortunately, I am getting this error.

```
class SignIn extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key, required this.onSignIn}) : super(key: key);
  final void Function(User) onSignIn;
  Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async {


    try {
      final anonymously = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
      onSignIn(UserCredential.user); // the error is in this parameter
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
// There is more code too but the issue is in this one
}
```

Comment: Please add the error that appears.

Comment: The error is in the title, but Yassin is right. It should also be placed in the question somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project runs with sound null safety. I guess the Udemy course is not using this feature of Flutter, yet. Since Flutter 2.2 sound null safety is enabled by default in new projects. You should check this page: https://dart.dev/null-safety

You can probably solve your issue by adding an exclamation mark behind the field that might be null like this: `onSignIn(UserCredential.user!);`

Comment: That's right. I have tried this and now I am not getting this error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by Null safety.

This feature has been recently included in Flutter, so it could be that the course you are following refers to an older version without Null safety.

You can read the docs here: https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the class type of the user parameter of the onSignIn function with the user parameter in UserCredential object.

You can include your full code for better clarity.

Or just the import statements of this file

Answer (score -1):

```
onSignIn(UserCredential.user!);
```

Just add the '!' after user and it is done, this error is due to null-safety, I think you are following an old course

Comment: Please edit your answer and include a detailed description with  professionally formatted code.